# Pagination on group by

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I have a record in my MySQL table which is something like:

id                         Postcontent         postdate

1                                A                         2013-01-31

2                         B                         2013-01-31

3                         C                         2013-01-30

4                         D                         2013-01-30

5                         E                         2013-01-29

6                         F                         2013-01-29

and I would like to show it in something like

2013-01-31

A

B

2013-01-30

C

D

2013-01-29

E

F

i can able to show like above with group by, but not able to add pagination in group by

if anyone can help me on how to add pagination in group by.

Comment: Could you show what code you have already tried ?

Comment: @Vikrant Randhawa posted an new approach for handling this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like this :

```
while( $row = $query_prepared->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC ) )
{
    if( $date <> $row['postdate'] )
    {
        echo '<br>' ,$row['postdate'];
    }

    $date = $row['postdate'];

    echo '<br>' ,$row['Postcontent'];
}
```

And no don't put `GROUP BY` in your SQL but use `ORDER BY postdate DESC` or ASC .

Here is an example just for understanding :

```
$testData = array
(
    array('1','A','2013-01-31'),
    array('2','B','2013-01-31'),
    array('3','C','2013-01-30'),
    array('4','D','2013-01-30'),
    array('5','E','2013-01-29'),
    array('6','F','2013-01-29')
);

$date = '';
foreach( $testData as $data )
{
    $row = array();
    list( $row['d'] ,$row['Postcontent'] ,$row['postdate'] ) = $data;

    if( $date <> $row['postdate'] )
    {
        echo '<br>' ,$row['postdate'];
    }

    $date = $row['postdate'];

    echo '<br>' ,$row['Postcontent'];
}
```

This will output :

```
2013-01-31
A
B
2013-01-30
C
D
2013-01-29
E
F
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

Make sure to have indexed postdate or even an index on (postdata, Postcontent) to get an covering index

**Note some people will see this as wrong because you format (HTML) with SQL now but you get much cleaner client code with this approach**

Run this query..

```
SELECT
   postdate 
 , GROUP_CONCAT(Postcontent SEPARATOR '<br />') 'postcontent_formatted'

FROM 
 your_table

GROUP BY
  postdate DESC
```

PHP code

```
<?php

     while( $row = $query_prepared->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC ) ) {
        echo $row['postdate'] . '<br />';
        echo $row['postcontent_html_formatted'] . '<br />';
     }

?>
```